# How to replace python dictionary to QueryDict with same key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a QueryDict from HttpRequest (request.POST) and I Have a new dictionary with same key. How can I insert or replace my new dictionary to QueryDict. any help will be appreciated.

```py
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['FEWFDFdcgfgrthBFFBDFBDF'], 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['13'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'],
             'form-0-publish': ['05/28/2019'], 'form-0-cell': ['81'], 'form-0-cell_name': ['13a'], 'form-0-jam': ['07.00-08.00'], 'form-0-target': ['60'], 'form-0-model_name': [''], 'form-0-article_no': [''], 'form-0-input_qty': [''], 'form-0-cementing_qty': [''], 'form-0-perbaikan_qty': [''], 'form-0-b_grade_qty': [''], 'form-0-diff_manual_output': [''], 'form-0-scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-0-total_scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-0-manual_output_qty': [''], 'form-0-total_manual_output': [''], 'form-0-scan_pack_qty': ['10'], 'form-0-component_upper_qty': [''], 'form-0-total_scan_pack': [''], 'form-0-grand_total_qty': [''], 'form-0-diff_output_component_upper': [''], 'form-0-problem': [''], 'form-0-tot_prod_hours': [''], 'form-0-tot_prod_ot': [''], 'form-0-time_normal': [''], 'form-0-time_ot1': [''], 'form-0-time_ot2': [''], 'form-0-time_ot3': [''],
             'form-1-publish': ['05/28/2019'], 'form-1-cell': ['81'], 'form-1-cell_name': ['13a'], 'form-1-jam': ['07.00-08.00'], 'form-1-target': ['60'], 'form-1-model_name': [''], 'form-1-article_no': [''], 'form-1-input_qty': [''], 'form-1-cementing_qty': [''], 'form-1-perbaikan_qty': [''], 'form-1-b_grade_qty': [''], 'form-1-diff_manual_output': [''], 'form-1-scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-1-total_scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-1-manual_output_qty': [''], 'form-1-total_manual_output': [''], 'form-1-scan_pack_qty': ['20'], 'form-1-component_upper_qty': [''], 'form-1-total_scan_pack': [''], 'form-1-grand_total_qty': [''], 'form-1-diff_output_component_upper': [''], 'form-1-problem': [''], 'form-1-tot_prod_hours': [''], 'form-1-tot_prod_ot': [''], 'form-1-time_normal': [''], 'form-1-time_ot1': [''], 'form-1-time_ot2': [''], 'form-1-time_ot3': [''],
             'form-2-publish': ['05/28/2019'], 'form-2-cell': ['81'], 'form-2-cell_name': ['13a'], 'form-2-jam': ['07.00-08.00'], 'form-2-target': ['60'], 'form-2-model_name': [''], 'form-2-article_no': [''], 'form-2-input_qty': [''], 'form-2-cementing_qty': [''], 'form-2-perbaikan_qty': [''], 'form-2-b_grade_qty': [''], 'form-2-diff_manual_output': [''], 'form-2-scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-2-total_scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-2-manual_output_qty': [''], 'form-2-total_manual_output': [''], 'form-2-scan_pack_qty': ['10'], 'form-2-component_upper_qty': [''], 'form-2-total_scan_pack': [''], 'form-2-grand_total_qty': [''], 'form-2-diff_output_component_upper': [''], 'form-2-problem': [''], 'form-2-tot_prod_hours': [''], 'form-2-tot_prod_ot': [''], 'form-2-time_normal': [''], 'form-2-time_ot1': [''], 'form-2-time_ot2': [''], 'form-2-time_ot3': [''],

my_dict={'form-0-publish': ['05/28/2019'], 'form-0-cell': ['81'], 'form-0-cell_name': ['13a'], 'form-0-jam': ['07.00-08.00'], 'form-0-target': ['60'], 'form-0-model_name': [''], 'form-0-article_no': [''], 'form-0-input_qty': [''], 'form-0-cementing_qty': [''], 'form-0-perbaikan_qty': [''], 'form-0-b_grade_qty': [''], 'form-0-diff_manual_output': [''], 'form-0-scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-0-total_scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-0-manual_output_qty': [''], 'form-0-total_manual_output': [''], 'form-0-scan_pack_qty': ['10'], 'form-0-component_upper_qty': [''], 'form-0-total_scan_pack': [''], 'form-0-grand_total_qty': [''], 'form-0-diff_output_component_upper': [''], 'form-0-problem': [''], 'form-0-tot_prod_hours': ['40'], 'form-0-tot_prod_ot': [''], 'form-0-time_normal': ['0.25'], 'form-0-time_ot1': [''], 'form-0-time_ot2': [''], 'form-0-time_ot3': [''],
         'form-1-publish': ['05/28/2019'], 'form-1-cell': ['81'], 'form-1-cell_name': ['13a'], 'form-1-jam': ['07.00-08.00'], 'form-1-target': ['60'], 'form-1-model_name': [''], 'form-1-article_no': [''], 'form-1-input_qty': [''], 'form-1-cementing_qty': [''], 'form-1-perbaikan_qty': [''], 'form-1-b_grade_qty': [''], 'form-1-diff_manual_output': [''], 'form-1-scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-1-total_scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-1-manual_output_qty': [''], 'form-1-total_manual_output': [''], 'form-1-scan_pack_qty': ['20'], 'form-1-component_upper_qty': [''], 'form-1-total_scan_pack': [''], 'form-1-grand_total_qty': [''], 'form-1-diff_output_component_upper': [''], 'form-1-problem': [''], 'form-1-tot_prod_hours': ['40'], 'form-1-tot_prod_ot': [''], 'form-1-time_normal': ['0.5'], 'form-1-time_ot1': [''], 'form-1-time_ot2': [''], 'form-1-time_ot3': [''],
         'form-2-publish': ['05/28/2019'], 'form-2-cell': ['81'], 'form-2-cell_name': ['13a'], 'form-2-jam': ['07.00-08.00'], 'form-2-target': ['60'], 'form-2-model_name': [''], 'form-2-article_no': [''], 'form-2-input_qty': [''], 'form-2-cementing_qty': [''], 'form-2-perbaikan_qty': [''], 'form-2-b_grade_qty': [''], 'form-2-diff_manual_output': [''], 'form-2-scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-2-total_scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-2-manual_output_qty': [''], 'form-2-total_manual_output': [''], 'form-2-scan_pack_qty': ['10'], 'form-2-component_upper_qty': [''], 'form-2-total_scan_pack': [''], 'form-2-grand_total_qty': [''], 'form-2-diff_output_component_upper': [''], 'form-2-problem': [''], 'form-2-tot_prod_hours': ['40'], 'form-2-tot_prod_ot': [''], 'form-2-time_normal': ['0.25'], 'form-2-time_ot1': [''], 'form-2-time_ot2': [''], 'form-2-time_ot3': ['']}

#new QueryDict I want
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['FEWFDFdcgfgrthBFFBDFBDF'], 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['13'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 
         'form-0-publish': ['05/28/2019'], 'form-0-cell': ['81'], 'form-0-cell_name': ['13a'], 'form-0-jam': ['07.00-08.00'], 'form-0-target': ['60'], 'form-0-model_name': [''], 'form-0-article_no': [''], 'form-0-input_qty': [''], 'form-0-cementing_qty': [''], 'form-0-perbaikan_qty': [''], 'form-0-b_grade_qty': [''], 'form-0-diff_manual_output': [''], 'form-0-scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-0-total_scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-0-manual_output_qty': [''], 'form-0-total_manual_output': [''], 'form-0-scan_pack_qty': ['10'], 'form-0-component_upper_qty': [''], 'form-0-total_scan_pack': [''], 'form-0-grand_total_qty': [''], 'form-0-diff_output_component_upper': [''], 'form-0-problem': [''], 'form-0-tot_prod_hours': ['40'], 'form-0-tot_prod_ot': [''], 'form-0-time_normal': ['0.25'], 'form-0-time_ot1': [''], 'form-0-time_ot2': [''], 'form-0-time_ot3': [''],
         'form-1-publish': ['05/28/2019'], 'form-1-cell': ['81'], 'form-1-cell_name': ['13a'], 'form-1-jam': ['07.00-08.00'], 'form-1-target': ['60'], 'form-1-model_name': [''], 'form-1-article_no': [''], 'form-1-input_qty': [''], 'form-1-cementing_qty': [''], 'form-1-perbaikan_qty': [''], 'form-1-b_grade_qty': [''], 'form-1-diff_manual_output': [''], 'form-1-scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-1-total_scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-1-manual_output_qty': [''], 'form-1-total_manual_output': [''], 'form-1-scan_pack_qty': ['20'], 'form-1-component_upper_qty': [''], 'form-1-total_scan_pack': [''], 'form-1-grand_total_qty': [''], 'form-1-diff_output_component_upper': [''], 'form-1-problem': [''], 'form-1-tot_prod_hours': ['40'], 'form-1-tot_prod_ot': [''], 'form-1-time_normal': ['0.5'], 'form-1-time_ot1': [''], 'form-1-time_ot2': [''], 'form-1-time_ot3': [''],
         'form-2-publish': ['05/28/2019'], 'form-2-cell': ['81'], 'form-2-cell_name': ['13a'], 'form-2-jam': ['07.00-08.00'], 'form-2-target': ['60'], 'form-2-model_name': [''], 'form-2-article_no': [''], 'form-2-input_qty': [''], 'form-2-cementing_qty': [''], 'form-2-perbaikan_qty': [''], 'form-2-b_grade_qty': [''], 'form-2-diff_manual_output': [''], 'form-2-scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-2-total_scan_bungkus': [''], 'form-2-manual_output_qty': [''], 'form-2-total_manual_output': [''], 'form-2-scan_pack_qty': ['10'], 'form-2-component_upper_qty': [''], 'form-2-total_scan_pack': [''], 'form-2-grand_total_qty': [''], 'form-2-diff_output_component_upper': [''], 'form-2-problem': [''], 'form-2-tot_prod_hours': ['40'], 'form-2-tot_prod_ot': [''], 'form-2-time_normal': ['0.25'], 'form-2-time_ot1': [''], 'form-2-time_ot2': [''], 'form-2-time_ot3': ['']
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `.dict()` (version >= 1.4):

```
print(request.POST.dict())
```

If your version < 1.4, do:

```
print(dict(request.POST.iterlists()))
```

Comment: I already do that but  I have 
(TypeError: dict() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. )

Comment: @rahmatzaki Try the first one

Comment: I try the first 'request.POST.dict(mydict)' but not work

Comment: @rahmatzaki NO, use `request.POST.dict()` please!

Comment: @rahmatzaki Can you please accept and up-vote if it works?